# javax.net.SSLException: Received fatal alert: unknown_ca

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, soap

I need to write soap ssl client with JAX-WS.
All configurations for this I've done like in this article:

http://lehvolk.blogspot.ru/2012/03/java-soap-implementations-with-ssl.html

When executing request, I receive following exception:

```
javax.net.SSLException: Received fatal alert: unknown_ca
```

Exception is thrown in `com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport:119`, when we try to `httpConnection.getOutputStream();`

It's clear from exception, that there is some problem with certificates.
So, I've exported resource's public certificate (export it from browser) and imported it in keystore. 
But this didn't helped me and now I don't have any idea what to do further.

Comment: First thing you can do is to check your SSL connection with the server side using OpenSSL. use the following command for debugging:  `opnessl s_client -connect host:443 -state -debug`